# Getting stuck in a loop, does local variable not visible to other workitems in a work group?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to use a local variable to syncronise among all the work-items in a work-group. However else part on conditional check always fails. Value of d[0] for other work-items does not equals to zero. Why local variable is not visible in the work-group?

I am using AMD APU A12-9800

```
__kernel void test(__global int *input_vector,__global atomic_int *mem_flag)
{
    local int d[32];
    if(get_local_id(0)==0) {
            d[0] = 100;
        }
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE| CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    while(1) {
        if(get_local_id(0) == 0) {
            d[0] = 0;
            break;
        }
        else {
            if(d[0] == 0)
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Compiler can optimize `if (d[0] == 0)` to be outside `while` loop since it cannot change (and local != volatile). I suggest you put the `barrier` inside the `while` loop so the write from local_id 0 can be seen be the other threads.

Comment: @Dithermaster can't include barrier inside the loop as first thread of each work-item exits before other thread. Hence leads to segmentation fault as all threads must hit the barrier.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `else` statement and instead put `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)`? All threads would be able to see that `d[0] = 0`, but that doesn't mean they'll all be in synch. Keep in mind the work-group might be larger than the number of threads the compute unit can run concurrently; you cannot expect "everything will run at the same time", or more precisely you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: Thanks @AlexG that really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @alexg I added the barrier along with else condition removed and it worked. Here is the full code

```
__kernel void test(__global int *input_vector,__global atomic_int *mem_flag)
{
    local int d[32];                                                  
    if(get_local_id(0)==0) {                                          
            d[0] = 100;
        }   
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE| CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);               
    while(1) {
            mem_fence(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE| CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);     
           if(d[0] == 0)
            break;
        if(get_local_id(0) == 0) {                                    
            d[0] = 0;   
        }   
    }     
}
```